# Python - Check for existence of list item within dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary with a list within like the 2 examples below.

```
some_json = {'speaking_tone': [{'speaking_id': 0, 'spoken_text': 'register my device', 'tones': []}]}

some_json = {'speaking_tone': [{'speaking_id': 0, 'spoken_text': 'So kind of you to help with the issue', 'tones': [{'tone_name': 'Polite'}]}]}
```

I want to check for the existence of values inside of "tones" and then do the subsequent processing. If not, proceed to the next step. I tried the following and they always result in index out of range error.

```
if len(some_json["speaking_tone"][0]["tones"][0]["tone_name"]) > 0:
```

Comment: You need more guards. For example, `some_json["speaking_tone"][0]["tones"] == []` in your first example, so of course you get an index out of range exception.

Comment: If the first example is possible, you cannot check for the 0 position in an empty array. Maybe you should check first if 'tones' is empty or not, and if not, check the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if `some_json["speaking_tone"][0]["tones"]` is an empty list? You'll get an error because you're trying to access something (`["tone_name"]`) from an empty list. To avoid that first check whether `some_json["speaking_tone"][0]["tones"]` is not empty.

```
some_json = {'speaking_tone': [{'speaking_id': 0, 'spoken_text': 'register my device', 'tones': []}]}

if len(some_json["speaking_tone"][0]["tones"]) == 0:
    print("Empty")
else:
    print("Something")


# Another way
if not some_json["speaking_tone"][0]["tones"]:
    print("Empty")
else:
    print("Something here")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any`:

```
some_json = {'speaking_tone': [{'speaking_id': 0, 'spoken_text': 'register my device', 'tones': []}]}
if any(i["tones"] for i in some_json["speaking_tone"]):
    pass
```

If you want to check if a target value exists in tones, you can try this:

```
target_val = "something"
if any(target_val in i["tones"] for i in some_json["speaking_tone"]):
    pass
```